# Buy Vietnamese Dong In Pune/Mumbai

Tags: indian-citizens, money, exchange, vietnam

I'll be travelling to Ninh Binh on 18th Dec, 2022 from Ahmedabad, India. But before I commence my travel, I want to convert INR to VND. I tried looking up some websites but couldn't gather much information. It would be really helpful if I could get some guidance on currency conversion from someone who has travelled from India to Vietnam.

PS: I'm currently located in Pune.

Comment: Did you check with your local travel agency?

Comment: @AnishSheela, Yes, in Pune there is Laxmi Forex. Tried getting it through them but was told that is very difficult to get VND. Instead suggested me to get USD.

Comment: If you get USD you'll have to onward convert that to VND in Vietnam. Certain tourist focussed services (mostly tours inc Halong Bay) accept or even require payment in USD, but most places its all local currency.

Comment: You can check in travel forums (such as Travel Talk on facebook) and someone might have currency left over from their trip

Answer (score 6):

It might be difficult to get not so common currencies in usual travel agencies and exchanges. You may have to go to a large scale exchange and the rates will be very less (due to less competition).

For Vietnam, the Visa on Arrival fees is collected in USD anyway. So, you don't need any money till you clear the procedures in airport and find an ATM.

I suggest you to use the ATM card and withdraw money overseas. It will be far profitable, as you will get better exchange rates than the brick and mortar stores. Some tips.

1. Remember to enable international payments and use the number which can receive the OTP overseas (JIO may not work without international roaming pack).
2. If the ATM offers to charge in the INR, decline and charge in Vietnamese dong only, as the rates will be worse.
3. Convert some money as USD anyway, as USD will be accepted at all exchanges and will usually get good rates. In case, you are stuck.

Comment: And check your card issuer fees for withdrawals and purchases abroad and for currency exchange! While many banks are reasonable and you will indeed get the best rate using your card in an ATM or for purchases, some will just charge through their teeth for such services. Of course check that your card can be used abroad (Visa or MasterCard logo). Use a debit card and not a credit card for ATM withdrawals.

Comment: @jcaron Yes. My Indian bank charges much. But it was way cheaper than going through a currency exchange.

Answer (score 5):

When converting one currency that is not commonly traded outside its country to another such currency, it is common that the calculation is made as if you converted to USD and then converted the USD again even if you never handle the USD.  In this case, at least one of the currencies will not be local, and we are supposing that these are not commonly traded outside their countries, so the rate for that one will probably be poor.

In your case, you might be able to get a good INR to USD rate in India but then you will probably get a poor USD to VND rate.  Conversely, in Vietnam you might be able to get a good USD to VND rate but a poor INR to USD rate.  The solution (assuming the need for cash) is simple: convert INR to USD in India and USD to VND in Vietnam.

Even with GBP, I have found this when travelling far from home.  I have travelled in Asia with friends.  I brought USD and they brought GBP.  Despite my double changing (GBP to USD in the UK before leaving), I typically got more local currency for the same GBP as they did.  In the worst case, I got about the same.

However, I have not checked recently as these days I use an ATM which usually beats any cash exchange.